# Swipe control weird on android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, device, swipe, gesture

So I am making a simple Basketball Shoot game, that use the swipe gesture (swipe down to up to throw balls).

When I use Unity remote 4 on my android device, everything works fine, when I swipe my finger, it throws a ball according to the swipe movement.

But when I build my app, and run it on my android device, the swipe gesture works, but it throw balls in other direction that doesn't match the swipe direction.
I run my app on two different devices, and they have different directions for the same swipe movement.

[image]

How can I fix that? do I need to setup something in unity player settings?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've noticed that the Unity Remote doesn't behave the same as when the game is running on the phone, sadly. The only solution is to make a build and push it to the phone and see what it does and try to figure out why it's not doing what you expect with log statements.

Comment: unity remote ***IS TOTALLY IRRELEVANT***.  it is only a wireless mouse.  DO NOT USE IT!!  it is one of the most truly stupid things in Unity.  And that's saying something.  Honestly, just never use it.

Comment: i was so happy when it works... Too bad it's not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using RayCast to detect swipe gesture. If that so then update your question with code snippet. We have to play bit smartly while using RayCast.

Comment: I bought FingerGesture and playmaker Asset so i can achieve this